# Fixing QGIS crashes when using GRASS toolbox

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation

I've installed QGIS 2.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. exactly as explained on qgis.org . Unfortunately QGIS crashes when trying to use any GRASS model (r.aspect as example):
just opening QGIS, click on toolbox expand toolbox, click on GRASS function r.aspect (as example) and it hangs... no error message, no possibility to define data for input!

It's probably a local problem. I've had QGIS 1.7.4 installed prior.

Additionally, I tried on a fresh ubuntu build (12.04) in a virtualbox. same results: when trying to us a function from Grass-toolbox it crashes QGIS.

Comment: Could you please add detail of the crash? Such as backtrace, or error message. Also, showing the exact commands you're running might be useful; and identifying which version of QGIS you installed would be good to know.

Comment: QGIS 2.0.1, I am doing nothing special: just opening QGIS, click on toolbox expand toolbox, click on GRASS function r.aspect (as example) and it hangs... no error message.

Comment: Please edit the question with this information, and also what data are you trying this on.

Answer (score 3):

You may have some "odd" stuff in your QGIS profile. For a test, rename the folder $HOME/.qgis2/ to some different name and try again.

If this does not help, please edit your posting and add some more info about your data.

Comment: as i have written above: no data is needed to reproduce the error as there was no data involved in producing the error.

Comment: So did you try to restart QGIS without your .qgis2 profile?

Comment: I have cleared the qgis2 folder and it was working. but nevertheless this should not occur on a fresh ubuntu qgis install